# Intent.Data received from sharing an image from gallery is null

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android

I'm trying to launch my app from the 'share' menu in image gallery apps. My problem is, the data of the intent I receive is null. How do I get the image from the intent?

```
[Activity(Label = "ShareActivity")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionSend },
    Categories = new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataMimeType = "image/*")]
public class ShareActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Intent.Data is null here
        if (Intent.Data != null)
        {
            var uri = Intent.Data;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the file URI is sent from the sharing app as Intent.ExtraStream and not Intent.Data.

### ShareActivity

Receives the intent from the image gallery and starts a new MainActivity intent while including the image as a byte array.

```
[Activity(Label = "ShareActivity")]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { Intent.ActionSend },
    Categories = new string[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataMimeType = "image/*")]
public class ShareActivity : Activity
{
    private string GetFilePath(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };
        var cursor = ManagedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null); // ManagedQuery is obsolete
        var colIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        return cursor.GetString(colIndex);
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        string fileUrl = string.Empty;
        if (Intent.Action == Intent.ActionSend && Intent.Extras.ContainsKey(Intent.ExtraStream))
        {
            fileUrl = GetFilePath((Android.Net.Uri)Intent.Extras.GetParcelable(Intent.ExtraStream));
        }

        if (fileUrl != string.Empty)
        {
            var image = File.ReadAllBytes(fileUrl);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            i.PutExtra("Image", image);
            this.StartActivity(i);
        }
        this.FinishActivity(0);
    }
}
```

### MainActivity

Gets the image from the intent from ShareActivity

```
protected async override void OnPostResume()
    {
        base.OnPostResume();
        if (Intent.Extras != null)
        {
            var image = Intent.Extras.GetByteArray("Image");
            // Do whatever
        }
    }
```